# When does the union of distinct cosets equal the group?

Tags: group-theory

I have an example where it's claimed that the union of distinct cosets of group $G$ spanned by $a$ and $b$, $a≠b$, equals the entire group $G$.

Is this a general property?

Comment: What do you mean by "spans"?

Comment: I believe it's the same term as "generates". It means that the entire group is given as the powers of $\mathbb{Z}$ of element $a \in G$. I.e. that $G=\{e, a, a^2, a^3, ...\}$.

Comment: In general this may not be true. If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, the quotient $G/H$ may be non-finitely generated.

Comment: @Crostul Even for finite groups, this will not in general be true.

Answer (score 0):

The union of distinct cosets is always the whole of a group. This is essentially how Lagrange's Theorem is proved (one shows that the relation $a$ is related to $ b \iff ab^{-1}\in H$ for a subgroup $H$ is an equivalence relation). However, if your subgroup $H$ is not normal then there is little more one can say in general. If it is normal, then the set of cosets forms a group $G/H$ where $aH*bH=(a*b)H$. In this case, you will find that if $G/H$ is generated by cosets $aH$ and $bH$ then, by your definition of spanned, any element from $aH$ along with any element from $bH$ will do the trick.